# Unable to get Location using opencellid.org Android

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-networking

i m using opencellid.org  to get location of Mobile from cell ID and Mnc and Mmcc and other information , i m able to get CellId , MNC, MCC , and LAC but not able to get location from these information Error showing  " **android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException**"

Here is Code

```js
public class OpenCellID {
    String mcc;  //Mobile Country Code
    String mnc;  //mobile network code
    String cellid; //Cell ID
    String lac;  //Location Area Code
     
    Boolean error;
    String strURLSent;;
    String GetOpenCellID_fullresult;;
     
    String latitude;
    String longitude;
     
    public Boolean isError(){
     return error;
    }
     
    public void setMcc(String value){
     mcc = value;
    }
     
    public void setMnc(String value){
     mnc = value;
    }
     
    public void setCallID(int value){
     cellid = String.valueOf(value);
    }
     
    public void setCallLac(int value){
     lac = String.valueOf(value);
    }
     
    public String getLocation(){
     return(latitude + " : " + longitude);
    }
     
    public void groupURLSent(){
     strURLSent =
      "http://www.opencellid.org/cell/get?mcc=" + mcc
      +"&mnc=" + mnc
      +"&cellid=" + cellid
      +"&lac=" + lac
      +"&fmt=txt";
    }
     
    public String getstrURLSent(){
     return strURLSent;
    }
     
    public String getGetOpenCellID_fullresult(){
     return GetOpenCellID_fullresult;
    }
     
    public void GetOpenCellID() throws Exception {
     groupURLSent();
     HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
     HttpGet request = new HttpGet(strURLSent);
     HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
     GetOpenCellID_fullresult = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity()); 
     spliteResult();
    }
     
    private void spliteResult(){
     if(GetOpenCellID_fullresult.equalsIgnoreCase("err")){
      error = true;
     }else{
      error = false;
      String[] tResult = GetOpenCellID_fullresult.split(",");
      latitude = tResult[0];
      longitude = tResult[1];
     }
       
      
    }
   }
   
   int myLatitude, myLongitude;
   OpenCellID openCellID;
   
    
     /** Called when the activity is first created. */
     @Override
     public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
          
         TextView textGsmCellLocation = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.gsmcelllocation);
         TextView textMCC = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.mcc);
         TextView textMNC = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.mnc);
         TextView textCID = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.cid);
         TextView textLAC = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.lac);
         TextView textGeo = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.geo);
         TextView textRemark = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.remark);;
         
         
         //retrieve a reference to an instance of TelephonyManager
         TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager)getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
         GsmCellLocation cellLocation = (GsmCellLocation)telephonyManager.getCellLocation();
         
         String networkOperator = telephonyManager.getNetworkOperator();
         String mcc = networkOperator.substring(0, 3);
         String mnc = networkOperator.substring(3);
         textMCC.setText("mcc: " + mcc);
         textMNC.setText("mnc: " + mnc);
         
         int cid = cellLocation.getCid();
         int lac = cellLocation.getLac();
         textGsmCellLocation.setText(cellLocation.toString());
         textCID.setText("gsm cell id: " + String.valueOf(cid));
         textLAC.setText("gsm location area code: " + String.valueOf(lac));
         
         openCellID = new OpenCellID();
         
         openCellID.setMcc(mcc);
         openCellID.setMnc(mnc);
         openCellID.setCallID(cid);
         openCellID.setCallLac(lac);
         try {
     openCellID.GetOpenCellID();
      
     if(!openCellID.isError()){
      textGeo.setText(openCellID.getLocation());
      textRemark.setText( "\n\n"
        + "URL sent: \n" + openCellID.getstrURLSent() + "\n\n"
        + "response: \n" + openCellID.GetOpenCellID_fullresult);
     }else{
      textGeo.setText("Error");
     }
    } catch (Exception e) {
     // TODO Auto-generated catch block
     e.printStackTrace();
     textGeo.setText("Exception: " + e.toString());
     Log.d("location is not valid",e.toString());
    }
     }   
  }
```

**Log cat showing no error**

```css
  : Flushing caches (mode 0)
   received file descriptor 48 from ADB
 D/ActivityThread(27520): BIND_APPLICATION handled : 0 / AppBindData{appInfo=ApplicationInfo{4180ddd8 com.example.cellid_areacode}}
   processIncoming
   processIncoming
   handlePacket : cmd=0x1, cmdSet=0xC7, len=0x13, id=0x4000010A, flags=0x0, dataLen=0x8
   REQ: DDM.Chunk (cmd=199/1 dataLen=8 id=0x4000010a)
   reply: dataLen=9 err=NONE(0)
   processIncoming
   handlePacket : cmd=0x1, cmdSet=0xC7, len=0x17, id=0x4000010B, flags=0x0, dataLen=0xC
   REQ: DDM.Chunk (cmd=199/1 dataLen=12 id=0x4000010b)
   reply: dataLen=104 err=NONE(0)
   processIncoming
   handlePacket : cmd=0x1, cmdSet=0xC7, len=0x13, id=0x4000010C, flags=0x0, dataLen=0x8
   REQ: DDM.Chunk (cmd=199/1 dataLen=8 id=0x4000010c)
   reply: dataLen=216 err=NONE(0)
   processIncoming
   handlePacket : cmd=0x1, cmdSet=0xC7, len=0x13, id=0x4000010D, flags=0x0, dataLen=0x8
   REQ: DDM.Chunk (cmd=199/1 dataLen=8 id=0x4000010d)
   reply: dataLen=9 err=NONE(0)
   processIncoming
   handlePacket : cmd=0x1, cmdSet=0xC7, len=0x14, id=0x4000010E, flags=0x0, dataLen=0x9
   REQ: DDM.Chunk (cmd=199/1 dataLen=9 id=0x4000010e)
   reply: dataLen=0 err=NONE(0)
 getDefaultSim is sim1
  create GsmCellLocation
  getDefaultSim is sim1
  getaddrinfo: www.opencellid.org  return error = 0x8 >>
   android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
    at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1099)
    at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:392)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:243)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:221)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:137)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:164)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:119)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:363)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:555)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:465)
    at com.example.cellid_areacode.MainActivity$OpenCellID.GetOpenCellID(MainActivity.java:80)
    at com.example.cellid_areacode.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:141)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4479)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1050)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2041)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2104)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:134)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1247)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4624)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:809)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:576)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
    location is not valid(27520): android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
    ActivityThread(27520): ACT-AM_ON_RESUME_CALLED ActivityRecord{4180f378 token=android.os.BinderProxy@4180eb00 {com.example.cellid_areacode/com.example.cellid_areacode.MainActivity}}
    ACT-LAUNCH_ACTIVITY handled : 0 / ActivityRecord{4180f378 token=android.os.BinderProxy@4180eb00 {com.example.cellid_areacode/com.example.cellid_areacode.MainActivity}}
    GC_CONCURRENT freed 194K, 4% free 9425K/9719K, paused 1ms+1ms
    loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLES_android.so
    loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libEGL_mtk.so
    loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_mtk.so
    loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv2_mtk.so
    Enabling debug mode 0
    threadid=11: interp stack at 0x4d174000
    showStatusIcon on inactive InputConnection
```

if i m not wrong , i have to write AsyncTask class , but i do not which function or code should i write in DoinBackground function in AsyncTask class.
Help will be appreciated
thanks in Advance

Comment: did u find any solution for that...

Answer (score 1):

My class with async task is as below

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private  OpenCellID openCellID;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
        GsmCellLocation loc = (GsmCellLocation) tm.getCellLocation();
        String networkOperator = tm.getNetworkOperator();
        String mcc = networkOperator.substring(0, 3);
        String mnc = networkOperator.substring(3);
        int cellid = loc.getCid();
        int lac = loc.getLac();
        openCellID = new OpenCellID();
        openCellID.setMcc(mcc);
        openCellID.setMnc(mnc);
        openCellID.setCallID(cellid);
        openCellID.setCallLac(lac);
        new GetLocation().execute();
    }
    class GetLocation extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {
        private Exception exception;
        protected Void doInBackground(String... urls) {
            try {
                try {
                    openCellID.GetOpenCellID();
                    if(!openCellID.isError()) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), openCellID.getLocation(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                return null;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                this.exception = e;
                return null;
            }
        }
        protected void onPostExecute(Void feed) {
            // TODO: check this.exception
            // TODO: do something with the feed
        }
    }
    public class OpenCellID {
        String mcc; //Mobile Country Code
        String mnc; //mobile network code
        String cellid; //Cell ID
        String lac; //Location Area Code
        Boolean error;
        String strURLSent;
        String GetOpenCellID_fullresult;
        String latitude;
        String longitude;

        public Boolean isError(){
            return error;
        }

        public void setMcc(String value){
            mcc = value;
        }

        public void setMnc(String value){
            mnc = value;
        }

        public void setCallID(int value){
            cellid = String.valueOf(value);
        }

        public void setCallLac(int value){
            lac = String.valueOf(value);
        }

        public String getLocation(){
            return(latitude + " : " + longitude);
        }
        public void groupURLSent(){
            strURLSent =
                    "http://www.opencellid.org/cell/get?key=15e7c7be-4d6c-42bc-a79c-23be75abcc87&mcc=" + mcc
                            +"&mnc=" + mnc
                            +"&cellid=" + cellid
                            +"&lac=" + lac
                            +"&fmt=txt";
        }

        public String getstrURLSent(){
            return strURLSent;
        }

        public String getGetOpenCellID_fullresult(){
            return GetOpenCellID_fullresult;
        }

        public void GetOpenCellID() throws Exception {
            groupURLSent();
            HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpGet request = new HttpGet(strURLSent);
            HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
            GetOpenCellID_fullresult = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
            spliteResult();
        }
        private void spliteResult(){
            if(GetOpenCellID_fullresult.equalsIgnoreCase("err")){
                error = true;
            }else{
                error = false;
                String[] tResult = GetOpenCellID_fullresult.split(",");
                latitude = "23.028431";
                longitude = "72.491422";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

One more suggestion add api key into your URL otherwise it won't give you result.

You can create api key from [this](http://opencellid.org/#action=database.requestForApiKey) link

Your url must be like this
http://opencellid.org/cell/get?key=15e7c7be-4d6c-42bc-a79c-23be75abcc87&mcc=405&mnc=030&cellid=19757464&lac=30001&fmt=txt